# vb.net search button multiple queries

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i am creating a program in vb.net and was wondering if there is a way to perform multiple queries with one button without adding a second button.

like i have two text boxes, one is for date and the other is for name. what i want to do is if i hit search and both the date and name boxes are filled, i want it to search for the name based on that date. but if only the name is filled i want to search for everything under that name.

This is what i have. right now it only does one search:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim myData As New DataTable
        Dim SQL As String
            SQL = "SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name " _
        & ", start.timestamp `Time In` " _
        & ", end.timestamp `Time Out` " _
        & ", timediff(end.timestamp, start.timestamp) Duration " _
     & "FROM user u " _
        & ", user_group ug " _
        & ", ( " _
           & "select * " _
              & ", ( " _
                 & "select event_id " _
                 & "from event L2 " _
                 & "where L2.timestamp > L1.timestamp " _
                    & "and L2.user_bannerid = ?bannerID " _
                     & "and L1.user_bannerid = ?bannerID " _
                 & "order by timestamp limit 1 " _
                & ") stop_id " _
           & "From event L1 " _
          & ") start " _
     & "join event end on end.event_id = start.stop_id " _
     & "where start.status = 'In' " _
        & "and end.status='Out' " _
        & "and u.user_bannerid = ?bannerID " _
        & "and start.user_bannerid = ?bannerID " _
        & "and ug.user_bannerid = ?bannerID " _
        & "and ug.group_id = ?GroupID " _
        & " and start.group_id = ?GroupID " _
     & "UNION " _
     & "SELECT null, null, null, CAST(sum(duration) as Time) " _
     & "FROM " _
     & "( " _
        & "SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name " _
           & ", start.timestamp `Time In` " _
           & ", end.timestamp `Time Out` " _
           & ", timediff(end.timestamp, start.timestamp) duration " _
        & "from user u " _
           & ", user_group ug " _
           & ", ( " _
              & "select * " _
              & ", ( " _
                 & "select event_id " _
                 & "from event L2 " _
                 & "where L2.timestamp > L1.timestamp " _
                    & "and L2.user_bannerid = L1.user_bannerid " _
                 & "order by timestamp " _
                 & "limit 1 " _
                & ") stop_id " _
              & "from event L1 " _
             & ") start " _
        & "join event end on end.event_id = start.stop_id " _
        & "where start.status = 'In' " _
           & "and end.status = 'Out' " _
           & "and u.user_bannerid = ?bannerID " _
        & "and start.user_bannerid = ?bannerID " _
        & "and ug.user_bannerid = ?bannerID " _
        & "and ug.group_id = ?GroupID " _
        & " and start.group_id = ?GroupID " _
     & ") total "
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnString

            Try
                conn.Open()

                Try
                    myCommand.Connection = conn
                    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("?bannerID", txtBannerID.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.Add("?GroupID", cboGroups.SelectedValue)

                    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                    myAdapter.Fill(myData)

                    dgvStatus.DataSource = myData
                    dgvStatus.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
                Catch myerror As MySqlException
                    MsgBox("There was an error reading from the database: " & myerror.Message)
                End Try
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to the database: " & myerror.Message)
            Finally
                If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
            End Try

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking the textboxes when the button is clicked. A query that complex may be rather difficult to work with directly, but it comes down to building the command string you want something like this:  (Way Simplified)

Query String building:

```
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT SomeFields FROM TableWhatever WHERE Date=?Date"
    If txtName.Text.Trim <> "" Then
        SQL &= " Name=?Name"
    End If
```

add parameter if its in the where clause

```
    ... Connection stuff here

    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
    If txtname.text.Trim <> "" Then
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("?Name", txtName.Text.Trim)
    End If
```